# How to reference a class method in another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

MY PYTHON VERSION IS 3.10

I'm trying to reference a method defined in the Button class (is_clicked()) in the Game class. The problem is the when I do it the way I'm doing it, the command prompt tells me:

```
   if Button.is_clicked(event.pos):
TypeError: Button.is_clicked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mouse_pos'
```

So I suppose that this error is the 'event.pos' argument is actually getting passed as self and not as mouse_pos. The question is that if there's a way to kind of "ignore" the self argument so that I can include the is_clicked() method as an event in my event_check() from the Game class. The thing is I'd like to reference every instance I create of the Button class but using Button.is_clicked() outside the Button class seems to not do the trick. Any help is pretty much appreciated

```
import pygame, sys

class Game:
    def __init__(self, resolution: tuple, fps: int = 24):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.font.init()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.resolution, pygame.RESIZABLE)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)
        self.fps = fps

    def get_clock(self):
        return self.clock

    def get_screen(self):
        return self.screen

    def get_resolution(self):
        return self.resolution

    def get_font(self):
        return self.font

    def tick_screen(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.clock.tick(self.fps)

    def event_check(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                # problem here :(
                if Button.is_clicked(event.pos): #REFERENCE THE BUTTON INSTANCE HERE


                    print("Button clicked!")
class Rect:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color

    # Draw the rectangle
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

class NarratingRect(Rect):
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color, font, text):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, color)
        self.font = font
        self.text = text

    # Draw the rectangle
    def draw(self, screen):
        super().draw(screen)
        text = self.font.render(self.text, True, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (self.x, self.y))

class Button(Rect):
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color, font, text):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, color)
        self.font = font
        self.text = text

    # Draw the button
    def draw(self, screen):
        super().draw(screen)
        text = self.font.render(self.text, True, (0, 0, 0))
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (self.x + self.width // 2, self.y + self.height // 2)
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)

    # Check if the button is clicked
    def is_clicked(self, mouse_pos):
        if self.x < mouse_pos[0] < self.x + self.width and self.y < mouse_pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: What's the point of adding the tags to the title?

Comment: This is not a pygame question. It is just a python question. Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). `Button` is not an instance, it is a class.  `is_clicked` is an instance method. You have to create an instance object of the class.

Comment: If you don't give button instance to `Button.is_clicked()`, then how can program get `self` related values in `is_clicked` function? If you want to make `is_clicked` as static function(to call as `Button.is_clicked()`), then you shouldn't refer `self` in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create instance to solve this issue, your methods are not static in that way.

```
buttonInstance = Button()
buttonInstance.is_clicked()
```

for more information you can check [Class Methods and Static Methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I myself reached the conclusion at what I wanted to do. Here's what I did:

- In the event_check() method I added a parameter as button_list, then with a for loop I check each button in the button_list list so that now it is an instance and therefore I can call the is_clicked() method.
- This solution requires to register every button after its creation, as simple as making another method to append it to the button_list and that all.

  ```
  if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
     if button_list is not None:
        for button in button_list:
           if button.is_clicked(event.pos):
               print("Button clicked!")
  ```

I dont think this is the fastest solution but i do think its a clever one.

```
  def register_button(self, button, button_list: list = None):
    if button_list is None:
        print("No button list provided!")
        return
    button_list.append(button)
```